# AWS WAF Log Utilisation + Penetration Testing with Web Applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, penetration-testing, amazon-waf

How can AWS Web Application Firewall help me in identifying which penetration testing I should use against my web application. Once i have access to the WAF Logs, how can I best utilise it to identify penetration testing.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the AWS WAF (or any WAF) is not a good indicator of what type of pentesting you should be doing. Determining the scope and type of pentesting is one of the most important first steps a qualified pentester or consultancy should be doing.

On the topic of WAFs, I would also say that they are not a good indicator of true manual pentesting. While the AWS WAF is great at catching SQL Injection and XSS test cases, it is not capable of detecting parameter tampering attacks.

So while it can create alerts that are likely to detect scans, it may fall short of detecting subtle human-driven test cases (which are often more dangerous).

To detect true pentest test-cases, it is always most valuable to add instrumentation at the application layer. This way you can create alerts for when a user tries to access pages or objects that belong to other users.

Also consider that if you create these alerts at the application layer, you can include more valuable data points such as the user and IP address. This will provide a valuable distinction between alerts that are create by random scanner on the internet, and ones created by authenticated users.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Really good details provided.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand what type of pentest you need, know what kind of regulation you want to comply with.

For example:

- PCI DSS may require Gray Box model for bank web application
- SOC2 could be fine with Black Box of web app(s)
- GDPR - OK with Black Box as well
- No compliance/regulator requirements? You can start with a Black Box approach for simple websites and apps, otherwise you can complex functional app

I strongly recommend to use at least Gray Box mode. Also you can refer to OWASP ASVS compliance requirements.